# SQL Server + Agent job calling CURL using Python

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute a `POST` call to an API inside a SQL Server Job using Python.

This is the Python script:

```py
import requests
    
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/searchkey=mykeyhere'
    
payload = open("request.json")
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Save the python to a .py file and call it from the [CommandLine](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) in a [CmdExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-cmdexec-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15) or  [PowerShell Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-powershell-script-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15) Agent job step.

Or skip Python and run the POST [directly from powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1).